# After frame convert processing by openCV, I want make rtsp stream. How to do it with GStreamer?

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I tried so many solution, but no any one doesn't work. This is my simple code for just get result (rtsp stream). It working without error, but I cant open rtsp stream.

And second question how to set stream name like rtsp://192.168.1.158:8554/test

First what I do, get camera's frame format from Basler camera
2. Creating video capturing
3. Getting current IP
4. Configuring pip_out string for rtsp streaming
5. Creating opencv writer
6. Read frame from camera and doing yolo detections (here not showed)
7. Showing result on local machine
8. Write frame to rtsp

VLC doesn't connect to rtsp. When I tried open it on local machine like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://localhost:8554 latency=100 ! 
queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! 
videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! 
Xvimagesink
```

It give me follow error:

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
> Progress: (open) Opening Stream
> Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://localhost:8554
> ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Could not > open resource for reading and writing.
> Additional debug info:
> gstrtspsrc.c(7469): gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp (): >/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPS
> rc:rtspsrc0:
> Failed to connect. (Generic error)
> ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.

```
import subprocess as sb
import shlex as sh
import cv2
import socket
import time

def get_frame_format():
    command = 'v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext'
    args = sh.split(command)
    p = sb.Popen(args,  stdout=sb.PIPE,  stderr=sb.STDOUT)
    res = p.communicate()[0].split()

    fps = float(res[-2].decode('utf-8')[1:])
    size = list(map (int , res[19].decode('utf-8').split('x')))
    width = size[0]
    height = size[1]
    return fps,  width,  height

fps,  width,  height = get_frame_format()    

print (f"fps: {fps}, {type(fps)}\n, size: {width} {height}")

window_title = "USB Camera"
camera_id = "/dev/video0"
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id,  cv2.CAP_V4L2)

#Get current IP for RTSP
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8",  80))
ip_address = s.getsockname()[0]


pipe_out = 'appsrc is-live=True ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=RGBA ! nvvidconv\
      ! omxh264enc insert-sps-pps=true ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream! h264parse \
      ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink port=8554 host=192.168.1.158'


rtsp_out = cv2.VideoWriter(pipe_out,  fourcc=0,  apiPreference=cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, fps=fps, 
                           frameSize=(1980, 1080),  isColor=True) 
time.sleep(2)
if not rtsp_out.isOpened() :
   print("Writer failed")
   exit()

print('Writer opened')

if cam.isOpened():
    try:
        window_handle = cv2.namedWindow(window_title, cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO )
        while True:
            ok, frame = cam.read()

            # Here  frame neuro processing by yolo
            
            # Showing result on local machine
            if cv2.getWindowProperty(window_title,  cv2.WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE) >=0:
                frame_out =  cv2.resize(frame,  (1980, 1080))
                cv2.imshow(window_title, frame_out)

                # result streaming to rtsp 
                rtsp_out.write(frame_out)
             
            else:
                break
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF  
            if key == 27 or key == ord("q"):
                break
    finally:
        rtsp_out.release()
        cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
     
else:
    print("Camera doesn't open")
```

'''

Comment: The port is wrong s.connect(("8.8.8.8",  80)). And your pipe_out is 8554.. you could use 8554 in s.connect.

Comment: Any luck? If not, I find a working GStreamer command line using RTSP, UDP at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77405617/5595995 would try with it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an RTSP server, but your pipeline uses a `udpsink`:

```
'appsrc is-live=True ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=RGBA ! nvvidconv\
      ! omxh264enc insert-sps-pps=true ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream! h264parse \
      ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink port=8554 host=192.168.1.158'
```

Those are two different elements. A `udpsink` "just" sends frames over UDP. An RTSP server does much more than that: it serves an RTSP API over which the client can download an SDP description, and then negociate UDP ports to open RTP stream(s) over UDP (or could be TCP), and also expose RTCP.

The simplest is probably to change your `gst-launch-1.0` pipeline to use `udpsrc` instead of `rtspsrc`.

If you really want to make an RTSP server, that's more complicated (especially since it comes from an `appsrc` in your case, I don't think you can do that from Python at all). So probably the easier way there would be to use your `udpsink`, and run an RTSP server that would consume it with `udpsrc`. The official implementation is [`gst-rstp-server`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/tree/main/subprojects/gst-rtsp-server), which has examples [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/tree/main/subprojects/gst-rtsp-server/examples), or maybe [this project called "rtsp-simple-server"](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server) may help.

I would suggest you do that in two steps:

1. Create a `gst-launch-1.0` pipeline using `udpsrc` and receiving the video from your python pipeline (the one with `udpsink` that you have above).
2. Once 1 works, try to feed this `udpsrc` pipeline into and RTSP server, either using `gst-rtsp-server` or `rtsp-simple-server`.

Comment: I can get the stream by this command on the same computer, this udp stream working is well. But can't get it on another computer use: video = cv2.VideoCapture('udpsrc port=8554 ! application/x-rtp ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse \
                         ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=xvimagesink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

ok, frame = video.read()

Comment: Isn't it because the "same computer" is `192.168.1.158`, and not the "other computer"?

Comment: I changed ip but can't catch the stream by opencv

Comment: Well you should probably experiment without OpenCV, e.g. using the gstreamer `videotestsrc` element. Once you get that working, you can add complexity. Doing everything at once is more difficult.