# Network Streaming (RTSP) but No Display in Receiving Side

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I try to stream, but I don't see any display in receiving side. This is my diagram:

One Image --> RTSP using UDP (using GStreamer) --> ?

Here is my command line and output in Terminal:

Sending (Server)
  from [Github post](https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim/issues/892#issuecomment-1680443810) with modification of "x264enc" --> "avenc_h263"
  IP address of the computer is 192.168.3.30.
`gst-launch-1.0 -v multifilesrc location=./IMG_7995.JPG loop=true ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! avenc_h263 ! rtph263ppay pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.3.30 port=6000`

```
** (gst-launch-1.0:11311): CRITICAL **: gst_ffmpeg_cfg_set_property: assertion 'qdata->size == sizeof (gint64)' failed
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstJpegDec:jpegdec0.GstPad:src: caps = "video/x-raw\,\ format\=\(string\)I420\,\ width\=\(int\)4032\,\ height\=\(int\)3024\,\ interlace-mode\=\(string\)progressive\,\ pixel-aspect-ratio\=\(fraction\)1/1\,\ chroma-site\=\(string\)mpeg2\,\ colorimetry\=\(string\)1:4:0:0\,\ framerate\=\(fraction\)0/1"
```

Receiving (Client)
  from [GStreamer example](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html?gi-language=c#network-streaming) with modification of "ffdec_h263" --> "avdec_h263" and remove "queue-delay=0" due to error of no element
`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=6000 ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000,payload=96 ! rtph263pdepay ! avdec_h263 ! xvimagesink`

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

I don't see any error (or error in output I just not notice?) in output, but there is no display. I actually performed [the Diagnostic] from GStreamer to verify my GStreamer installation and it is good. I also switched computer between sending and receiving sides.

I am expecting a video play the image from sending side at receiving computer.

What I miss in my GStreamer pipelines? Thanks.

Runtime Environment
  OS: Ubuntu 18.04 receiving and 16.04 sending
  GStreamer: 1.14.5 receiving and 1.8.3 sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try rtph263pay instead of rtph263**p**pay.

The following works for me:

Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v multifilesrc location=./IMG_7995.JPG loop=true ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! avenc_h263 ! h263parse ! rtph263pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.3.30 port=6000
```

Receiver (192.168.3.30):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc address=192.168.3.30 port=6000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H263 ! rtph263depay ! h263parse ! avdec_h263 ! queue ! xvimagesink
```

Comment: I tried to run the command line, but it looks like "h263parse" not in version 1.14.5 (somehow 1.8.3 had it - I checked with `gst-inspect-1.0 | grep 263`). How to add "h263parse"? Or is there equivalent?

Comment: I'm using gstreamer 1.16.3 and h263parse is from videoparsersbad. Do you have gst-plugins-bad installed ? That being said, in my case h263parse is not mandatory, you may try omitting it.

Comment: Thanks for the versions. I will try the "bad" first. It looks like without "h263parse" not showing video.

Comment: I'd suggest that you first try on localhost with: `gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! avenc_h263 ! rtph263pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=6000` and test from same host with:  ̀`gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=6000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H263 ! rtph263depay ! avdec_h263 ! queue ! autovideosink`

Comment: (1) "h263parse" installed with "bad" version - Thanks. (2) I tried "127.0.0.1" and "videotestsrc" (also "multifilesrc location=./IMG_7995.JPG loop=true") but still not showing a video...Are the both commands at the same computer (instead of two different machines), right? (3) I am running in remote session by NoMachine. Will it affect anything?

Comment: Please be sure to try the commands from my previous comment, I deleted a previous one that was wrong (comments cannot be edited after some time...). 
Yes both commands are to be run on same machine.
I don't think that NoMachine may be a problem here, though if you can try local login and display it may save some potential issues.
You may post the output logs from both commands (or a link to these).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255820/discussion-between-seb-and-cloud-cho).